# Axios response promise object but need promise value

Tags: vue.js, promise, axios, vue-component

I request it with the get method.

```
async getPrograms() {
    const response = window.axios.get('http://localhost:8000/programs')
    console.log(response);
}
```

The rotating response is as follows.

[image]

The part I need here is the data in `[[PromiseValue]]`. But I don't know how to get here. I'm writing my code with Vue js. How do I get the data in `[PromiseValue]]`?

Comment: `await` the promise.

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't see how to do this. @tkausl

Answer (score 0):

Since axios.get returns a promise, use `await` to wait for the promise to resolve

```
async getPrograms() {
    const response = await window.axios.get('http://localhost:8000/programs')
    console.log(response.data);
}
```